# installation of openscenegraph windows

Tags: installation, windows-7-x64, openscenegraph

I don't know how I should ask this question. If I make any mistakes, I would appreciate it if someone could correct them.

I just start learning `openscenegraph` and try to install it in my `Windows7`. I open [this website](http://www.openscenegraph.com/index.php/download-section/stable-releases) but puzzled with the files that which one should I download and run.

Can you please guide me step by step installation process?

Comment: Are you going to code with `Visual Studio`? Are you using `MinGW`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just open [this link](http://trac.openscenegraph.org/projects/osg//wiki/Downloads/PreviousReleases) and install this file `Win32 binaries installer .exe`

Or you can also follow [this video](http://youtu.be/1l5PAVCj2iY?list=LLY3zJkqe4kk-5LEMQ0dHCww) as well this one is the latest one